# How to retrieve 2 object fields from Salesforce using SOQL

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, soql, salesforce-communities

I'm trying to retrieve 2 object fields using Salesforce queries SOQL
Product

1. Product2
2. PricebookEntry

Both these objects have product Code = "CUCR05RC002"

I want to combine these 2 queries

Product2

```
SELECT id 
FROM product2 
WHERE productcode = "CUCR05RC002"
```

PricebookEntry

```
SELECT id 
FROM pricebookentry 
WHERE productcode = "CUCR05RC002"
```

Here is Product Page inside of it we have Price Book

[image: Product page]

This is Price Book page have same Product Code as Product

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

"bottom up" (from pricebook entry up to product)

```
select Id, Product2Id, Product2.Id, Product2.Name
FROM PricebookEntry
WHERE productcode='CUCR05RC002'
```

"top down" (from product go down to related list of pricebook entries")

```
select Id, Name,
    (select id from PricebookEntries)
FROM Product2
WHERE productcode='CUCR05RC002'
```

You use one or another depending on what you need. Multiple products? All entries from 1 pricebook?